# "Forced update" shown after git pull

Tags: git

After I did `git pull` in my repository, it is showing

```
6cca7ee...32eb5b2 bug/12 -> origin/bug/12  (forced update)
```

Previously, I created `bug/12` branch from parent branch `parent/1.2.3`, made changes in the code, and merged the `bug/12` branch in the `parent/1.2.3` branch and finished `bug/12 branch`. But due to some problem I need to again reopen the bug 12 and therefore I again created a `bug/12` branch from `parent/1.2.3` and did the code changes and pushed the changes to `bug/12` branch. But now when I have taken the pull on `parent/1.2.3` branch it is showing me forced update.

So, if I merge my newly created `bug/12` branch in `parent/1.2.3` branch will it create any problem or will that forced update be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "forced update" thing can be very confusing, but you have asked an important question.

Whether there is any actual problem here—I suspect there isn't—depends on what *you* mean when you say:

> ... and finished `bug/12 branch`.

Git does not have a concept called *finishing*.  So it's not obvious what actual Git operations you caused to happen, in which repositories.

#### Git is distributed, so there is more than one repository

If there were only one repository, and it had various branch names like `bug/12` and you did something like:

```
git checkout master
git merge bug/12
git branch -d bug/12
```

(which would merge the commit at the tip of `bug/12` to `master`, then *delete* the branch name `bug/12`) this kind of problem would never come up: having *deleted* the name, it no longer exists.

But there isn't just one repository.  You:

- created the name `bug/12` in *your* repository
- did some work in *your* repository, creating commits
- sent those commits to *another* repository and had *them* create the name `bug/12` in *their* repository
- had your Git obtain new commits and/or branch names from them: this found that they now had a `bug/12` in *their* repository, so your Git created an `origin/bug/12` in *your* repository to remember *their* `bug/12`

Now, after all of this, I *suspect* that what you did—what *you* mean by "finished `bug/12 branch`"–is that you were using GitHub or Bitbucket or GitLab or similar, and you went onto their web interface and used the various little clicky buttons to merge `bug/12` into `master` in *their* repository, and then *deleted their `bug/12` name*.  This is very similar to the three hypothetical commands shown above, except that `git merge bug/12 could do a fast-forward operation instead of a true merge, while the GitHub *merge pull request* button will never do a fast-forward operation.

But I don't *know* that this is what you did.  I merely *suspect* it.

#### Stale remote-tracking names

Assuming that this *is* what you did, you probably went on to manually delete the branch name `bug/12` from your own repository:

```
git branch -D bug/12
```

Since then, you've probably run `git fetch` (or had `git pull` run `git fetch` in a way that would fix things up), but you probably *don't* have `fetch.prune` set to `true`.  When you run `git fetch`, your Git calls up the Git over at `origin` and has them list out their branch names.  They *don't have a `bug/12` branch name at this point*, but your Git made your own `origin/bug/12` earlier, when they *did* have their `bug/12` branch name.  Your Git therefore does nothing with your own `origin/bug/12` name: there is no new value for this name, but you didn't instruct your Git to *delete* `origin/*` names that no longer have another name.

This means that as far as your Git is concerned, `origin/bug/12` is still remembering a valid `bug/12` name in the other Git repository, *even though there is no such name any more*.  Had you set `fetch.prune` to `true` or run `git fetch --prune`, your Git would have deleted this `origin/bug/12`.  So at this point, your `origin/bug/12` is a *stale name*.  (Git does not define this term—it has no concept called *stale names*—but this seems like a good term for this kind of name.)

Again, all of this is deduction from facts not actually in evidence.  Is this really what happened?  I cannot know: you have not told me enough.

#### Stale names can result in this kind of behavior

Now, assuming that all of the above is correct, your own `origin/bug/12` remembers what `bug/12` on `origin` remembered some time ago.  That was *before* you clicked on a *merge* or *rebase and merge* or *squash and merge* web-browswer clicky button.  At this point, I must make at least one more assumption: that the button you used was not a pure *merge* but rather *rebase and merge* or *squash and merge*.

Let's draw the situation before a rebase-and-merge or squash-and-merge operation.  You have, in the Git repository over on GitHub—I'm going to assume GitHub at this point—a series of commits, each ending at a commit to which some branch name(s) point:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- bug/12
```

Here `E` and `F` are the two commits that fix the bug.  You now click on either *rebase and merge* or *squash and merge* and get either two or one new commit:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E'-F'  <-- parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- bug/12
```

or:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G   <-- parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- bug/12
```

(I'll go with this drawing because it's simpler).  You now have GitHub delete *its* `bug/12` name:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G   <-- parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   [abandoned]
```

At some point, in *your* repository, you update your own Git's memory of the GitHub Git's branches:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G   <-- origin/parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/bug/12
```

Note how your stale `origin/bug/12` name is still remembering commit `F`!

At this point you may or may not add even more commits to `origin/parent/1.2.3` and/or bring your own `parent/1.2.3` name up to date.  Let's draw in one more commit and show these two in sync:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- parent/1.2.3, origin/parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/bug/12
```

Remember, this is a drawing of what is in *your* repository.  The GitHub repository has this instead:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- parent/1.2.3
```

It has no `origin/*` names: it has only *its* branch names.  *Your* Git is the one with the `origin/*` names, including the stale `origin/bug/12`.  By now, *their* Git has completely discarded commits `E-F`.  *Your* Git is still keeping the otherwise unwanted `E-F` commits, due to your `origin/bug/12` name.

Now you do something in *their* Git that creates the name `bug/12`, pointing to commit `H`:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- parent/1.2.3, bug/12
```

You now run `git fetch` (via `git pull`) in *your* repository.  Your Git sees *their* `bug/12` pointing to commit `H`.  Your Git *currently* has this:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- parent/1.2.3, origin/parent/1.2.3
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/bug/12
```

but your Git is now going to take *your* `origin/bug/12` and yank it off of commit `F` and move it to point to commit `H` instead:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- parent/1.2.3, origin/parent/1.2.3, origin/bug/12
         \
          E--F   [abandoned]
```

**Your Git now does this unusual motion** of *your* name `origin/bug/12`, yanking it from a commit that you are still keeping—commit `F`—over to commit `H` that is *not* a *descendant of* commit `F`.  (Commit `H`'s only parent is `G`.  `G`'s parent is `D`, whose parent is `C`, whose parent is `B`.  Commit `H` is therefore not a *descendant of* `F`, although they both share the same ancestry at commit `B`.)  This operation is a *non-fast-forward* and therefore *your* Git prints:

```
+ 6cca7ee...32eb5b2   bug/12 -> origin/bug/12  (forced update)
```

The plus sign at the front (which you omitted) indicates that this is a *forced update* because it is a *non-fast-forward*.

The two hash IDs here, `6cca7ee` and `32eb5b2`, are abbreviated versions of the full hash IDs of the commits I have been calling `F` and `H` above.  The output from `git fetch` includes the three-dots between these two hash IDs, indicating that `6cca7ee` is not an ancestor of `32eb5b2`.

The name `bug/12` on the left side of the arrow is the branch name as seen in *their* repository (over on GitHub, or wherever that is).  The name `origin/bug/12` is *your Git's memory* of their `bug/12`.

The `(forced update)` at the end indicates the same thing as the plus sign and the three dots: that this was a non-fast-forward, and therefore was done as a forced update.

The `git fetch` command has therefore told you three times that there was a forced update.

#### Is there a problem here?

The answer is *probably not*, but it depends, not on this change to your `origin/bug/12`, but rather on *your own* branch names.  In the drawings above, we've been drawing in some of your branch names, some of your *remote-tracking* `origin/*` names, and some of the other Git's branch names, depending on which Git repository we are talking about.  But we have not been drawing in *all* of your branch names.

*Your* branch names are *yours*.  They can point to any commit you have in your repository—including the `E-F` commits that the *other* Git, over on GitHub or wherever it is, has jettisoned.  If you allow one of your branch names to *re-introduce* those old commits, that's probably not good.  If you don't allow this, that's fine.  If you don't *have* any branch names that point to these old commits, you won't accidentally re-introduce them.

That is the key to the puzzle.  *Commits* are what matter.  Commits have commit hash IDs, and *every Git everywhere in the world* agrees that *those* commits get *those* hash IDs.  No other commit, anywhere or any time, can have those hash IDs!  *Your* Git still had them under *your* remote-tracking name, `origin/bug/12`.  It no longer has them under that name: that *name* has been updated to remember some other commit hash ID.  But you still have *your* branch names.  Do any of these remember the same hash ID as the stale `origin/bug/12` you had up until the `git fetch` that your `git pull` ran updated it, just recently?

Only *you* can answer this, because only you have *your* Git repository.